# MediaController with ExoPlayer: skipToNext() & skipToPrevious() not working

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x, mediacontroller, android-mediasession

I am trying to hook up my Media Player's UI to to ExoPlayer that's running in a MediaBrowserCompatService so that when i touch play/pause, fast forward, rewind etc. will work.

From within my activity i call:

```
mediaController.transportControls.play() / .pause()
mediaController.transportControls.fastForward() / .rewind()
```

And this works perfectly.

Calling:

```
mediaController.transportControls.skipToNext() and
mediaController.transportControls.skipToPrevious()
```

though don't work at all.

In my MediaBrowserCompatService I have set the appropriate media playback state on the media session but
programmatically calling skip to previous and next won't work.

```
 stateBuilder = PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY
                        or PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE
                        or PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT
                        or PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS)
 setPlaybackState(stateBuilder.build())
```

The exoplayer is prepared with ConcatenatingMediaSource() and skipping to the next and previous track from the Media Notification is working though.

Anyone any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have to explicitly add a QueueNavigator MediaSessionConnector.
So something like this:

```
val mediaSessionConnector = MediaSessionConnector(mediaSession)
val queueNavigator = object : TimelineQueueNavigator(mediaSession){
        override fun getMediaDescription(player: Player?, windowIndex: Int): MediaDescriptionCompat {
            return mediaItems[windowIndex].description
        }
    }
 mediaSessionConnector.setQueueNavigator(queueNavigator)
```

With the queueu navigator set it isn't necessary to set:

```
PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT
or PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS
```

on the stateBuilder.

Comment: Correct, when specifying a queue navigator, these actions are added and handled for you. Another frequent pitfall I see is overriding the MediaSession by creating another callback: note that MediaSessionConnector implements the callback under the hood, so things are likely to break by specifying one manually.